# How to avoid selecting the same elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

Assume there two lists:`A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];B=[23,25,34,23,24,10,45]`. The elements in `A List` represent the name of products, while those in `B list` represent the price of products. For example, product 1 worths 23 USD.
I want to retrieve the products whose price is 23 USD.
What I tried was shown below:

```
Prod_23 = []
for i in B:
  if i == 23:
    index = B.index(i)
    product = A[index]
    Prod_23.append(product)
```

The result was:

```
Prod_23 = [1,1]
```

But the actual result should be like:

```
Prod_23 = [1,4]
```

Could you please give me some clues of avoiding selecting the first element twice and only selecting  the first and fourth elements?

Comment: You should read up on the `index` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip()` to *tie* lists A and B together and use list-comprehension:

```py
list_23 = [a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b == 23]
print(list_23)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use any of the following methods for this purpose:

### Python2 :

```
>>> indices = [A[i] for i in xrange(len(A)) if B[i] == 23]
>>> indices
[1, 4]
>>>
```

### Python3:

#### Using a for-loop with [**`range()`** <sup>[Python-docs]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) :

```py
>>> indices = [A[i] for i in range(len(A)) if B[i] == 23] # or [A[i] for i in A if B[i] == 23]
>>> indices
[1, 4]
>>>
```

#### Using for-loop and [**`enumerate()`** <sup>[Python-docs]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) :

```py
>>> indices = [A[i] for i, x in enumerate(B) if x == 23]
>>> indices
[1, 4]
>>>
```

#### Using [**`locate()`** <sup>[more-itertools-docs]</sup>](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=locate#more_itertools.locate) with for-loop:

```py
>>> from more_itertools import locate
>>> indices = [A[i] for i in locate(B, lambda x: x == 23)]
>>> indices
[1, 4]
>>>
```

#### Using [**`locate()`** <sup>[more-itertools-docs]</sup>](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=locate#more_itertools.locate)  with [**`itemgetter()`** <sup>[Python-docs]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```py
>>> from more_itertools import locate
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> indices = list(itemgetter(*locate(B, lambda x: x == 23))(A))
>>> indices
[1, 4]
>>>
```